# Kanji changing to boxes in Excel when I switch from Japanese to English input

Tags: microsoft-excel, language, japanese

I'm creating a database that includes a column of Japanese amidst many columns of English, but every time I switch my input language to English, the kanji turn to boxes with the character 字 inside them. I'm not sure if this will continue you when I turn the Excel database into a searchable online database. The problem resolves itself when I switch back to Japanese input, but it's very weird and makes me worried. 
Do any of you have any idea what's going on with this?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the problem resolves itself when you switch back to Japanese implies that your content is still there, intact.  When you switch to the English language input, Excel is changing its view encoding to a Western character set that doesn't include kanji so it can't display them.  As long as your online search function supports the appropriate Japanese character set, it should work okay.